# NHibernate Set Property Default Value

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Is it possible to set the default value of a property in NHibernate? Here is the scenario:

I have a self join table `Category`. The class and table structure are as follows:

```
Category
int Id
string Name
Category ParentCategory

Category
int Id not null
varchar Name not null
int ParentCategoryId not null
```

If a category has no parent, the `ParentCategoryId` must be 0.

How do I do this? TIA.

Answer (score 0):

If nHibernate is enforcing this relationship I don't believe you can make it form an invalid relationship. I'd create a dummy parent record 0 in the database and just assign everything to that.

Comment: Thanks Spencer for the idea, however we can't do that since we are only integrating to an existing application.

Answer (score 0):

If the ParentCategoryId is not constrained by a foreign key, then you can have in your code ... something like :

```
class Category{
   ....

   public static Category NoParent{
     get{ return new Category{Id = 0}; }
   }


   ....
}
```

and now, instead of setting to null, just set it to NoParent. Or in the setter of ParentCategory, if value is null, then set it to NoParent.

This is basically **Spencer Ruport's** ideea :P

Comment: @sirrocco, how would you reflect that in the mappings?

Comment: by the way, I already tried that. Assigning a category instance with id = 0 to the parentcategory property, but to no avail.

Comment: What do you mean by no avail ? was it throwing an error or what ?